# Scala in depth - Existential types

Tags: scala, types

I am currently reading Scala in depth and I struggle with a point about existential types.

Using those sources : https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-in-depth-source/blob/master/chapter6/existential-types/existential.scala

with openjdk 7 and scala 2.10.3

The following instructions gives me a error :

```
val x = new VariableStore[Int](12)
val d = new Dependencies {}
val t = x.observe(println)
d.addHandle(t)

<console>:14: error: method addHandle in trait Dependencies cannot be accessed in types.Dependencies
 Access to protected method addHandle not permitted because
 enclosing object $iw is not a subclass of 
 trait Dependencies in package types where target is defined
              d.addHandle(t)
                ^
```

And I can't find out why and how I arrive to this error.

**Edit 1 :**
I added the following code from Kihyo's answer :

```
class MyDependencies extends Dependencies {
  override def addHandle(handle: Ref) = super.addHandle(handle)
}

val x = new VariableStore[Int](12)
val d = new MyDependencies
val t = x.observe(println)
d.addHandle(t) //compiles
```

It make addHandle public instead of protected.

Now I have the following error message :

```
type mismatch; found : x.Handle (which expands to) x.HandleClass required: d.Ref (which 
 expands to) x.Handle forSome { val x: sid.types.obs.Observable }
```

HandleClass is a Handle and Ref is a Handle of any Observer (if I get it right) so the value t should be accepted as a correct type for the exception.

Comment: Edit1: The code compiles and runs without problems on my machine. Did you add anything? Post full code when you did.

Comment: Here is the complete code : https://gist.github.com/Daroth/9450049 It worked in a console, but when I added TestObs (line 105) it does not compile (line 112 on d.addHandle(t))

Answer (score 1):

In the trait `Dependencies`, `addHandle` is defined like that:

`protected def addHandle(handle : Ref) : Unit`

`protected` means, only subclasses can access this method and thats why you get the error. (which basically tells you exactly that)

Your code could work when you create a subclass that makes `addHandle` public:

```
class MyDependencies extends Dependencies {
  override def addHandle(handle: Ref) = super.addHandle(handle)
}

val x = new VariableStore[Int](12)
val d = new MyDependencies
val t = x.observe(println)
d.addHandle(t) //compiles
```

But I have no idea about that example and what you want to do with it.

@Edit1:

I get the same error as you, but I can't explain why. It worked for me when I extend App instead of having a main-method:

```
object TestObs extends App {
  val x = new VariableStore[Int](12)
  val d = new MyDependencies
  val t = x.observe(println)
  d.addHandle(t)
}
```

Maybe someone else has some insight on this.