# What is the difference between Generics and Existential types in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm confused about when to use generics vs when to use existential types. To be honest I have no idea what an existential type is.

What is the difference between the following?

```
def foo[T](arr: Array[T]) = ...
def foo(arr: Array[T] forSome {type T}) = ...
```

Comment: You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374610/when-to-use-existential-type-in-scala?rq=1), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444958/what-is-the-forsome-keyword-in-scala-for?rq=1), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282731/scala-in-depth-existential-types?rq=1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646416/confusion-with-existential-types-in-scala?rq=1) as a start. If something is still unclear, update your question with a more specific request.

Comment: Ah thanks. I did try searching but obviously not hard enough.